# How to specify the $schema for a JSON array

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a json schema for an array. The schema is correct and my array can validate against it. Now I would like to define the schema in the json like i could do with an object like this :

```json
    {
       "$schema": "pathtomyschema",
       "prop1": "value",
       ...
    }
```

Obvisouly I can't simply set $schema in the array like this :

```json
    [
       "$schema": "pathtomyschema",
       { "prop1": "value" },
       ...
    ]
```

So, is there any way to do this ?
The goal here is to help people create their json with schema reference.

Comment: Is the root element in your JSON an array? If so, no, you cannot do this.

Comment: Yes it is, thanks for you answer, I will change my root element to an object then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$schema` does not work on JSON instances in general. it is a keyword for schemas to declare what metaschema they use. information on what schema describes an instance is out-of-band to the instance.

if your instance is accessed over http, the recommended method to communicate what schema describes an instance is the 'describedby' link header - see http://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.9.5.1.1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my case its for an internal project and the goal is only to provide auto-completion/validation for those who will have to write json to use my service.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using JSON Schema to validate our JSON files and also provide auto-suggestion for a while in our project.

The idea is pretty simple: for every JSON resource, we create a `.schema.json` file that defines the structure and types of the JSON files. For example, we have:

- `resources.json` (The file)
- `resources.schema.json` (The Schema)

Our JSON files, start with a reference to the schema file like this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "./schemas/resources.schema.json",
   ...rest of the JSON data
}
```

We're using VSCode to manually update these files, so our team and our contributors have a way to validate our JSON input as well as having auto-suggestion and type-checking through the schema, which is pretty neat and keeps our JSON files consistent with the schema. The validation can also happen automatically using the appropriate tooling (scripts) that will validate the JSON files according to the `.schema.json` files.

Since JSON schemas can import or reference other schema files, we've managed to split various part of the schema into different files according to their content. We have for example references to HTML, CSS and JS concepts, educational material types, etc.

You can take a look at the [resources.json file here](https://github.com/in-tech-gration/WDX-180/blob/main/resources/resources.json) and the corresponding schema [here](https://github.com/in-tech-gration/WDX-180/blob/main/resources/schemas/resources.schema.json).

If you switch to the GitHub `dev` [mode](https://github.dev/in-tech-gration/WDX-180/blob/main/resources/resources.json), you can even check the validation yourself (see screenshots).

We've been quite happy with how it works for some time now and ChatGPT has been a great help for us to find the appropriate syntax for the schema.

A great tool that also helps the process, is a VSCode extension called [ErrorLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens) which immediately highlights and displays validation errors inline. We are mostly using VSCode for updating these JSON files.

Hope this helps you, your team or anyone struggling with strict JSON structures.

[image]

[image]